# List of coincidences with Python

Tags: python

So, I have various txt files, filled with words organized as a list, and I want to create a file that contains the elements of every txt file who is also in another txt file. I tried with this:

```
    cadena = []
    cadena_dos = []
    seccion = ""
    filename_LISTA = "LISTA_FINAL.txt"
    linea_vacia = "\n"
    espaciador = "----------------------------------------------\n"
    cacho = "     "
    repeticiones = []
    cachito = " | "
    inicio = "Is also in "
    espacio = ", "

    fe = open(filename_LISTA, "w")

    nombres = ["ONE", "TWO", ... "ELEVEN"]

    for i in range (0, len(nombres)):

        filename = nombres[i]
        filename_a = filename + ".txt"
        filename_b = filename + "\n"

        linea = str(cacho)
        fe.write(linea)
        linea = str(nombres[i])
        fe.write(linea)
        linea = str(linea_vacia)
        fe.write(linea)
        linea = str(linea_vacia)
        fe.write(linea) 

        with open(filename_a) as f:
            data = f.readlines()


            for n, line in enumerate(data, 1):
                cadena.insert(n-1, line.rstrip())
                normal = str(cadena [n-1])


                for p in range (1, len(nombres)):

                    filename_dos = nombres[p]
                    filename_a_dos = filename + ".txt"

                    if filename_a != filename_a_dos:


                        with open(filename_a_dos) as t:
                            data = t.readlines()

                        for r, line in enumerate(data, 1):    
                            cadena_dos.insert(n-1, line.rstrip())
                            normal_dos = str(cadena_dos [n-1])


                            if normal == normal_dos:  
                                repeticiones.append(filename_dos)

             if len(repeticiones) > 0:

                    linea = normal
                    fe.write(linea)
                    linea = str(cacho)
                    fe.write(linea)
                    linea = str(cachito)
                    fe.write(linea)
                    linea = str(inicio)
                    fe.write(linea)
                    for cont in range (0, len(repeticiones)):

                        linea = str(repeticiones[cont])
                        print repeticiones[cont]
                        fe.write(linea)
                        if cont < len(repeticiones):
                            linea = str(espacio)
                            fe.write(linea)
                        else:
                            linea = str(linea_vacia)
                            fe.write(linea)

                else:
                    linea = str(linea_vacia)
                    fe.write(linea)

                repeticiones = []


            linea = str(linea_vacia)
            fe.write(linea)
            linea = str(espaciador)
            fe.write(linea)
            linea = str(linea_vacia)
            fe.write(linea)

    fe.close()
```

But doesn´t do anything. The problem is that if I delate the line

```
"filename_a != filename_a_dos:"
```

The program start to function but start to find coincidences within the same txt file. Can anyone help get this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making your `filename_a_dos` value using the outer loop's `filename`, not the inner loop's `filename_dos`. This means that `filename_a_dos` will always be the same as `filename_a`, since they're both `filename + ".txt"`.

You could further improve your loops a bit by using [`itertools.combinations`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations), rather than looping twice over the filename list, but that's a larger change that's not directly related to the issue you're currently having.

Comment: Thanks! Haven´t thought of that. I´ll try with the itertools.combitions as you suggest, seems a better way to proceed

Answer (score 1):

Thats because the value of filename_a and filename_a_dos is always the same, so the content inside

> filename_a != filename_a_dos:

wont work.

I think u may mean

> filename_a_dos = filename_dos + ".txt"